# Custom UITableViewCell re-creating itself

Tags: objective-c

Really need help. I've looked everywhere but still i cant find an answer. So, when i scroll my UITableView with custom cells in it its recreating cell each time I see it. As the result it lowers my performance significantly.

my method

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellWithViewForProduct";
ProductCell *cell = (ProductCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
ProductDataStruct *dataStruct = [self.arrayData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"productCell" owner:nil options:nil];
    for(id currentObject in topLevelObjects)
    {
        if([currentObject isKindOfClass:[ProductCell class]])
        {
            cell = (ProductCell *)currentObject;
            break;
        }
    }
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.roundingIncrement = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:0.01];
formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;

NSString *price = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:(dataStruct.price.floatValue * [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"CurrencyCoefficient"] floatValue])]];
NSString *priceString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", price, [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Currency"]];

cell.productPrice.text = priceString;
cell.productDescription.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", dataStruct.descriptionText];
cell.productTitle.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", dataStruct.title];

if (dataStruct.hit.integerValue == 1)
{
    [cell.productImage.layer addSublayer:[hitView layer]];
}
else
    if (dataStruct.hit.integerValue == 2)
        [cell.productImage.layer addSublayer:[newsItemView layer]];

if (!dataStruct.image)
{
    if (self.tableView.dragging == NO && self.tableView.decelerating == NO && dataStruct.link)
    {
        [self startIconDownload:dataStruct forIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
    // if a download is deferred or in progress, return a placeholder image  
    //cell.productImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Placeholder.png"];

    // if a download is deferred or in progress, return a loading screen
    cell.productImage.alpha = 0;
    [cell.productImageLoadingIndocator startAnimating];

}
else
{
    if (self.didLoad)
    {
        cell.productImage.alpha = 0;
    }
    [cell.productImageLoadingIndocator stopAnimating];
    cell.productImage.image = dataStruct.image;
    [self imageAnimation: cell.productImage];
}
NSLog(@"WAZAAA");
return cell;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'it's re-creating' - what does recreate it? How?

Comment: cells are not 'created every time'. They're created once.

Comment: In table i have 40 elements. when I scroll down and up - the message appears 80 times

Comment: and at some point application just stuck and I can nothing to do

Comment: @userXXXX of course it does appear 80 times, because the delegate method is called each time for every visible cell. But it doesn't mean a new cell is created every time it's called. What do you think the call to `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` is for?

Comment: so you're telling me this is not the reason my app stucks?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Next time please read the documentation for a method before you try to use it.

Comment: Then can you please check is there any mistakes in it that can provoke such thing? I'm new in objective-c, so I can't find the reason.

Comment: @userXXX maybe you should not reload the NIB in every call to this method. You should really put that in the initialization.

Answer (score 1):

This entire chunk of code:

```
NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"productCell" owner:nil options:nil];
for(id currentObject in topLevelObjects)
{
    if([currentObject isKindOfClass:[ProductCell class]])
    {
        cell = (ProductCell *)currentObject;
        break;
    }
}
```

seems wrong to me.  Above it,

```
ProductCell *cell = (ProductCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

should be sufficient to get you a cell to use.

Answer (score 0):

first create a `@property (nonatomic, assign) IBOutlet ProductCell *prodCell;` in the `.h`

Then in the .m you just need this

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellWithViewForProduct";

    ProductCell *cell = (ProductCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"productCell" owner:self options:nil];

        cell = prodCell;

        self.prodCell = nil;
        NSLog(@"WAZAAA"); //Now it will only be called when a new cell is created.
    }

NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.roundingIncrement = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:0.01];
formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;

NSString *price = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:(dataStruct.price.floatValue * [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"CurrencyCoefficient"] floatValue])]];
NSString *priceString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", price, [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Currency"]];

cell.productPrice.text = priceString;
cell.productDescription.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", dataStruct.descriptionText];
cell.productTitle.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", dataStruct.title];

if (dataStruct.hit.integerValue == 1)
{
    [cell.productImage.layer addSublayer:[hitView layer]];
}
else
    if (dataStruct.hit.integerValue == 2)
        [cell.productImage.layer addSublayer:[newsItemView layer]];

if (!dataStruct.image)
{
    if (self.tableView.dragging == NO && self.tableView.decelerating == NO && dataStruct.link)
    {
        [self startIconDownload:dataStruct forIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
    // if a download is deferred or in progress, return a placeholder image  
    //cell.productImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Placeholder.png"];

    // if a download is deferred or in progress, return a loading screen
    cell.productImage.alpha = 0;
    [cell.productImageLoadingIndocator startAnimating];

}
else
{
    if (self.didLoad)
    {
        cell.productImage.alpha = 0;
    }
    [cell.productImageLoadingIndocator stopAnimating];
    cell.productImage.image = dataStruct.image;
    [self imageAnimation: cell.productImage];
}
NSLog(@"WAZAAA"); //Here doesn't make any sense, the cell is returned for being displayed, this doesn't mean it's being created.
return cell;
}
```

Comment: I may have missed it, but the only time I see you using the property is when it's set to nil—why is the property necessary?

Comment: The property have a IBOutlet, so you can link it to a custom cell nib. You only create a new cell from the nib when the cell is nil

Comment: Even as an IBOutlet, I don't see you accessing the property—the only time `self.prodCell` appears in your code is in the line `self.prodCell = nil;`.

Comment: look at the cell = prodCell; I forgot the self. because in my code I have a @syntesize, so I don't need the self. in any of the prodCell. With the cell = prodCell, I load the nib into the cell, and then I change the nib properties with the cell. code.